# Creating a dictionary with keys representing elements from a list

Tags: c#, linq

I want to create a `Dictionary` where the `Key`s are representing elements from a `List`. Each list element has to be present in this dictionary.

Example:
A movie has a list of actors.

Now I want a list of movies the actor acted in. If the movies have more than one actor, each actor should have the movie in their own list.

I have a data strucuture like this:

```
public class MovieData
{
    public List<string> Actors { get; set;}
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

A small **example** to illustrate this:

```
var movie1 = new MovieData { 
  Title  = "Movie1", 
  Actors = new List<string> { "Bob Smith", "Alice Stevens"}};

var movie2 = new MovieData { 
  Title  = "Movie2", 
  Actors = new List<string> { "Alice Stevens"}};

var movie3 = new MovieData { 
  Title  = "Movie3", 
  Actors = new List<string> { "John Doe" }};
```

The desired **result** should look like this:

```
Alice Stevens => { "Movie1", "Movie2" }
Bob Smith     => { "Movie1" }
John Doe      => { "Movie3" }
```

I came up with the following code, but it only pays attention to the first actor in the list (`FirstOrDefault()`). So other actors in the list are ignored.

```
var actorMovieList = movieDataList
  .ToLookup(movie => movie
                       .Actors
                       .FirstOrDefault(), movie => movie);
```

How can I include the other actors in the list? I have to iterate through the actor list inside of the lambda, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `SelectMany` to *flatten* the initial `List<List<string>>` into

```
{actor, title}
```

records and then put `GroupBy` to group them by `actor` into required dictionary:

```
var result = movieDataList
  .SelectMany(movie => movie
     .Actors
     .Select(actor => new {    // from now we have flat cursor of
        actor = actor,         // {actor, title} records
        title = movie.Title
      }))
  .GroupBy(record => record.actor,  // ... which we group by actor: 
           record => record.title)  // actor and movies (s)he played in 
  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, // or ToLookUp() 
                group => group.ToList());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can flatten the `movieDataList` first (using `SelectMany` method) into collection of actors and movie titles and then use [`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=netframework-4.8) method with this collection. It allows you to include all authors in the final result

```cs
var movieDataList = new List<MovieData>() { movie1, movie2, movie3 };

var result = movieDataList
    .SelectMany(m => m.Actors
        .Select(a => new
        {
            Actor = a,
            Movie = m.Title
        }))
    .ToLookup(pair => pair.Actor, pair => pair.Movie);

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} {string.Join(",", item)}");
}
```

The output will be the following

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick solution which provides the desired results:

Let's say you have a movie data list like this:

```
var movieDataList = new List<MovieData> { movie1, movie2, movie3 };
```

First, let's extract all the actors:

```
// NOTE: Used ToHashSet() in the end to avoid the duplicates in the names
var actors = movieDataList
    .SelectMany(item => item.Actors)
    .ToHashSet();
```

Now let's craft the dictionary which contains the name of the actor and list of movies

```
var allActorMovieList = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach (var actor in actors)
{
    // List of the movies of the actor
    var actorMovieList = movieDataList
        .Where(movieData => movieData.Actors.Contains(actor))
        .Select(movieData => movieData.Title)
        .ToList();

    allActorMovieList.Add(actor, actorMovieList);
}
```

Now `allActorMovieList` contains all the actors with their films

Answer (score 2):

```
var flatQuery = 
  from movie in movies
  from actor in movie.Actors
  select new {movie, actor};

var lookup = flatQuery.ToLookup(
  pair => pair.actor,
  pair => pair.movie.Title);

var aliceStevensMovies = lookup["Alice Stevens"].ToList();
var amyBMovies = lookup["Amy B"].ToList(); //empty, not keyNotFound
```